# Test double for ActivatedRoute not working

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-activatedroute

The Angular documentation mentions a test double for ActivatedRoute:

```
import { convertToParamMap, ParamMap, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

  export class ActivatedRouteStub {
    private subject = new ReplaySubject<ParamMap>();

    constructor(initialParams?: Params) {
      this.setParamMap(initialParams);
    }

    readonly paramMap = this.subject.asObservable();

    setParamMap(params?: Params) {
      this.subject.next(convertToParamMap(params));
    };
  }
```

But when I use this in my component -

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TypesComponent } from './types.component';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRouteStub } from './../../testing/activated-route-stub';

describe('Component', () => {
let component: TypesComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TypesComponent>;
let activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteStub;

beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ TypesComponent ],
        providers: [
            { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ActivatedRouteStub}            
        ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    activatedRoute = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
});

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TypesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should get...', () => {
    activatedRoute.setParamMap({ id: 1});
    spyOn(service, 'method').and.returnValue(1);
    expect(service.value).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
   });
});
```

But this gives the error:
[image]

Edit: This error persists regardless of where I place the `.setParamMap()` - whether in the `it()` or in `beforeEach()`.

I understand I can simply use an observable instead of the stub,but out of curiosity, any idea what I'm doing wrong here? What should I do to get this working ?

Comment: Can you share the ActivatedRouteStub ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it `async`

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    activatedRoute.setParamMap({ id: 1 });
  }
```

Comment: You have `useValue`. Try `useClass`. Or `useValue: activatedRoute`

Comment: With useClass : Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRouteStub: (?).

`useValue: activatedRoute` won't work since till that line activatedRoute is undefined. It has only been declared.